# Retrieving Child of Material Design UI Kit Card

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, material-design-in-xaml, materialdesignthemes

I know it is possible to retrieve the children of a container such as a `WrapPanel`:

`UIElementCollection collection = myWrapPanel.Children;`

Assume that I have a `MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.Card` that contains a container like a `WrapPanel`.

Note that I don't know the `Name` of that container!

my question is that...

How to retrieve the child of a `MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.Card`?

Comment: Looking at the source code, a card is a contentcontrol so you can put whatever you like in it as it's content. Could be a stackpanel or a grid or a control. And they could have children.

Comment: Iterating controls is not how I would usually work. I'd work with data in the bound viewmodel.

Comment: So, do you have any solutions in code?

Comment: Do u Have some content property or something like data source

Comment: Only you know what you put in that card. The solution depends on what that is. The parent or only control will be the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to retrieve the child of a MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.Card?

Cast its `Content` property to whatever the type of the "child" is, e.g.:

```
var panel = card.Content as Panel;
var children = panel?.Children;
```